# NodeJS cannot read some RaspberryPi GPIOs

Tags: gpio, pi-4

I want to read 5 buttons from RaspberryPi.
I installed the latest 64-bit OS bullseye on brand-new Raspberry 4B.
But somehow only GPIO23 can be read, the other GPIOs can not. When I connect GPIO23 to GND, it prints "23 value: 0" as expected, but nothing is shown for other GPIOs when I connect them to GND.

```
const Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;

gpioPins = [ 17, 27, 22, 23, 24]

for(let i = 0; i < gpioPins.length; i++){
        temp = new Gpio(gpioPins[i], 'in', 'falling');

        (function(gpiox) {
        console.debug(gpiox);
                gpiox.watch((err, value) => {
                        if (err) {
                                throw err;
                        }
                        console.debug(gpiox._gpio, " value: ", value)
                });
        })(temp);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to configure 'pull up' in /boot/config.txt as it seems the onoff library can't do that? https://github.com/fivdi/onoff#using-the-gpio-command-in-bootconfigtxt

Comment: Please edit the question and explain "it shows the value, but the values of other GPIOs are not shown."

Comment: I edited question.

Comment: Perhaps they are already at a low level?

Answer (score 1):

After comment of @CoderMike, I set the GPIOs pull-up in the /boot/config.txt and it works now!
I had to add `gpio=17,22,23,24,27=ip,pu` into /boot/config.txt